# How to use ESP32 ESP32 config flag in platformio?

Tags: esp32, platformio

I build my ESP32 project from platformio and I'd like to change CONFIG_MBEDTLS_DYNAMIC_FREE_PEER_CERT in order to reduce the RAM footprint.
I don't get how to do that: should I modify my platformio.ini?

Comment: If you are using arduino-esp in platformio, then you have to build the sdk yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you have to update your platformio.ini as assumed in the question as follows (see last line):

```
[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32dev
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200
lib_deps = 
    adafruit/Adafruit NeoPixel@^1.10.0
    plerup/EspSoftwareSerial@^6.13.2
    miwagner/ESP32CAN@^0.0.1
    nilsminor/TMP117-Arduino@^1.0.2
    lbernstone/Tone32@^1.0.0
board_build.partitions = no_ota.csv
build_flags = -DCONFIG_MBEDTLS_DYNAMIC_BUFFER
```